# No video output during post and GRUB until OS is fully up

Tags: linux, windows, boot, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

UPDATE:
I've tested a couple of things now.

- Displaying the BIOS and GRUB actually works, if you go into Windows, select Restart into advanced options (Shift + Reboot) and then select to boot into UEFI settings. So I assume the BIOS knows how to deal with the 3070. Might a delay in the boot process fix that?
- A BIOS update did not fix the issue
- There is also no difference, when I plug my monitor into the iGPU

*A couple of months ago I built myself a new high-end desktop PC, which I use for professional workloads (mostly programming and running demanding ML/AI stuff) and gaming in my freetime aswell...*

I set it up with Debian 11 and Windows 11 Pro. I use Debians GRUB as my boot-manager.
Every time I start up the system, the display doesn't get an output from my nVidia RTX card during post and the whole boot process, untill either of the OSs is fully up and running. Windows only shows anything when it arrives at the login page (not even the loading screen with the turning circle appears). Not even Debians quiet or splash boot options display anything until the login page appears aswell... I have no idea, where that might ocme from.

For now, I've not had enough time to dive into the issue, so I left it and just "remembered" where the different options are on GRUB and I selected them by "counting" my arrow-key presses, to select the right OS. Now I still don't have time to fix it , so I am asking if someone has had this issue before or if its a common thing to happen, which is relatively easy to solve. But I'm not in a rush here, since it is just a convenience thing...

FYI:
On Debian I am using the proprietary nVidia drivers for the RTX 3070, since the nVidia-nouveau drivers seemed to glitch out and prevented Debian from booting. There were temporary fixes for that on the GitHub issues page, but each of them would have required plenty of time for me to implement, since I have not much experience with the Linux-Kernel itself.
My boot priority order is: Debian EFI first (since it automatically launches GRUB) and Windows Bootmngr. as the second option.

Comment: This could be explained by the BIOS looking for a non-existent integrated graphics adapter, so no output before the operating system is advanced enough in the boot.

Comment: @harrymc Why would it do this and is there a way to change this in the BIOS settings? My CPU has an iGPU. It's an Intel Core i7 10700. I'll quickly check, if I get any "early output", if I plug my screen into the mainboards DP, instead of the dedicated GPUs. I haven't found any obvious setting for changing the default graphics adapter...

Comment: Yes, the BIOS is perhaps not capable of using the RTX 3070.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out, that the pretty simple answer to this lies in the BIOS of the graphics card!

There is a setting within the RTX 3070s BIOS, which determines the default video output port when no drivers are loaded, for example at boot.
For my card, this was set to the HDMI port instead of one of the three DP-ports, which I tried to use, so naturally, the screen stayed black until the OS, including the drivers, was loaded.

After the graphics driver determines the cards output to be one or multiple ports with an output device connected, the card 'remembers' that setting, until it gets powered down, which reverts it to its default state, determined by the BIOS.

That means, if for example Windows gives a reboot command, the whole system goes through a reboot, without cutting power to the card, keeping the drivers port settings for it loaded, resulting in an output via DP when the system POSTs!

So that's the mystery solved.

The default output of the card can be changed by flashing an updated BIOS, which is not recommended though... (connecting a screen to the default port, if its really necessary, is the safer option.)

*Disclaimer: I can't say whether this is the default behavior for any RTX 3070, since my specific model is from Zotac and I got it used, so there is no guarantee, that the cards BIOS hasn't been tampered with.)*